# Split a flat HTML document into sections by tags - Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a flat HTML document where different elements are separated by H2 tags:

```html
<h2>section 1</h2>
other elements in the section...
<h2>section 2</h2>
other elements in the section...
```

I need to split document in to hierarchical sections using BS4.. this is basically what I am looking forward to doing:

```html
<section>
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  elements following the previous H2
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  elements following the previous H2 
</section>
```

How to go about it with BS4/XPATH or CSS selectors?

I need to get the elements between the two H2 tags using BS4...

of course I can linearly traverse the DOM tree (the current document is actualyl more like a flat array) and chunkify, but that would be ugly...

Comment: So you want a simple text file document as output?

Comment: @MartinEvans not really, I can do the transformation later... basically waht I'm looking for is to group the *flat array* of HTML elements into sections (demarcated by the H2 header)... I can linearly scan the entire DOM and put the elements into chunks.. but I was wondering if there was an easier way to do it with beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup does let you insert tags, so you could add `<section>` tags around the `<h2>text` elements as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from copy import copy

html = """<html><body>
<h2>section 1</h2>
other elements in the section...
<h2>section 2</h2>
other elements in the section...    
</body></html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    section_soup = soup.new_tag('section')
    section_soup.append(copy(h2))
    section_soup.append(h2.next_sibling)
    h2.insert_before(section_soup)
    h2.extract()
    
print(soup)
```

Giving you an updated HTML as:

```
<html><body>
<section><h2>section 1</h2>
other elements in the section...
</section><section><h2>section 2</h2>
other elements in the section...    
</section></body></html>
```

This works by first creating a new section tag and adding a copy of the `<h2>` tag into it followed by the text following it. It then inserts this new soup before the existing `<h2>` tag. Finally it removes the original `<h2>` tag.